# Spring Security перенаправляет style.css

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

В моём проекте используется Spring Security, который до определенного момента прекрасно работал и не вызывал никаких затруднений.
Но какое-то время назад при загрузке веб-приложения  он начал перенаправлять файл стилей на /login, хотя доступ к папке со стилями у меня прописан в WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/reg", "/registration/**", "/static/**", "/static/images/**", "/static/styles/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .failureUrl("/login_error")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/pc")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/"));


        return http.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT email, password, active FROM users WHERE email = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT email, role FROM roles JOIN users ON users.user_id " +
                        "= roles.iduser WHERE email=?");
    }
```

Перенаправление видно через инструменты разработчика в гугл https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpRXd.png

C чем это может быть связано?
Буду очень благодарна за любую помощь, потому что уже не знаю, что с этим делать.

Comment: на скриншоте вижу запрос `localhost:8080/styles/style.css` , упущено `static`, должно быть `localhost:8080/static/styles/style.css`